# Login flow using LoginActivity and Kinvey

Tags: android, authentication, kinvey

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        // Flag for login flow
        private boolean flag = true;

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mKinveyClient.user().login(mEmail, mPassword, new KinveyUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(User user) {
                    CharSequence text = "Welcome back," + user.getUsername() + ".";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    CharSequence text = "Wrong username or password.";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    flag = false;
                }
            });

            return flag;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password_or_username));

                mEmailView.setText("");
                mPasswordView.setText("");

                mEmailView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
```

I need the method to return true or false based on whether or not the user successfully logged in or not. However, the `flag` value doesn't change within the `onFailure` method.

Answer (score 1):

Check if any of the below exceptions are thrown on failed login. 
[From the document,](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html#onFailure(java.lang.Throwable))

```
void onFailure(java.lang.Throwable caught)
```

is Called when an asynchronous call fails to complete normally. IncompatibleRemoteServiceExceptions, InvocationExceptions, or checked exceptions thrown by the service method are examples of the type of failures that can be passed to this method.
If caught is an instance of an IncompatibleRemoteServiceException the application should try to get into a state where a browser refresh can be safely done.

Parameters:
caught - failure encountered while executing a remote procedure call